# WCF netTcpBinding Get Username

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a self hosted WCF service using netTcpBinding. Is there a class that I could use to access the domain username of the client calling the service. I tried looking in the `OperationContext` but could not figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this:

```
ServiceSecurityContext serviceSecurityContext = ServiceSecurityContext.Current;
if (serviceSecurityContext != null)
{
  string accountText = serviceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name;
}
```

The WindowsIdentity property contains a lot of information about the user.